# Program to find out whether a Matrix is symmetric or not via Transpose

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

I think the problem is with the comparison of the pointer `ptr` and with the pointer of the new array `ptr2`. But I’m not sure at all.

First of all I let the user type in an array of 2D and then I turned the array via its pointer into a Transpose and since arrays in C++ are actually 1D arrays in row major order I tried to just compare the values the pointers to the two arrays are pointing at. Somehow I don't know why but it’s not working. I know that it is maybe not the most efficient way but I want to learn and know why it’s not working.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool transponierte(int *ptr, int groesse, int c, int r) {
  bool symmetrisch;
  int array_neu[r][c];
  for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
      array_neu[j][i] = *ptr;
      ptr++;
    }
  }

  int *ptr2 = &array_neu[0][0];
  for (int i = 0; i < groesse; i++) {
    if (*ptr == *ptr2) {
      symmetrisch = true;
    }
    if (*ptr != *ptr2) {
      symmetrisch = false;
      break;
    }
    ptr++;
    ptr2++;
  }

  return symmetrisch;
}

int main() {
  int r, c;
  cout << "how many columns " << endl;
  cin >> c;
  cout << "how many rows " << endl;
  cin >> r;

  int array[c][r];
  int groesse = r * c;
  for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      cout << "type in elemts for the array" << endl;
      cin >> array[j][i];
    }
  }

  bool trans = transponierte((int *)array, groesse, c, r);
  if (trans == true) {
    cout << "the matrix is not symmetric " << endl;
  }
  if (trans == false) {
    cout << "the matrix is not symmetric" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't do all this raw pointer arithmetic in C++ it is not recommended to do so (too easy to access memory that's nor yours).  Replace `int*` with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` (and learn about passing by reference).

Comment: I know thats its not the best way, but I want to understand :(

Comment: What does your debugger have to say about all this?

Comment: Think about what `ptr` is after your transposition loop.

Comment: @Botje the last element of the origin array ? Well pointing at it .. or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Ramyz How do you know whether it works? You print out the same thing in any case.

Comment: @Ramyz Variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature.

Comment: @Biffen that's why it is not working

Comment: @VladfromMoscow what does that mean ? so what

Comment: @Ramyz It means that sizes of arrays shall be compile-time constant expressions.

Comment: Always compile with ALL warnings enabled, like this : https://godbolt.org/z/dTv7GzPoz
And you will see this warning ; `<source>:5:22: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]` indicating you are using something that is not part of standard C++. In C++ you should use `std::vector` in those cases

Comment: Not complying with the standard means other people may not be able to compile your code. In general never ignore compiler warnings and fix the root cause.

Comment: okay I changed the if statement at the end it should be` if ( trans == true) { cout << "is symmetric " << endl; `but it is still not working

Comment: A matrix is symmetric if it is square and `matrix[x][y] == matrix[y][x]` for all values of `x` and `y` in the range. Try programming it exactly that way instead of all the pointer tricks. Keep the notation appropriate to the problem domain.

Comment: You're missing mypoint, fix the broken C++ first. You are writing "C" code not C++. Why are you hanging on to pointer arithmetic (Is this your teacher asking you this?) Both ptr and ptr2 point to integers, not rows, not columns. So ptr2 isn't magically going to skip rows by incrementing it.

Comment: @user207421 That's what I keep telling him... including the example below.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I know I’m sorry , I will do it today. I thought that incrementing the pointer is no problem because multidimensional arrays are actually 1dimensional in the memory :( it is driving me crazy that’s why I keep asking. If I would do it in another way I wouldn’t learn why this doesn’t work..

Comment: Pointers still have their uses, but as a way to access memory in arrays (of any dimension) is best left to internals of datastructures that can safeguard invariants (and ensure pointer arithmetic will never go out of bound). And even then things like std::span are more safe to use. And yes multidimensional arrays are contiguous in memory, but you still need to know the strides for each dimension. C++23 is going to add a nice (safe) feature for accessing multidimensional arrays in the way you want : this called [mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan)

Comment: As to why it doesnt work : increase one step in column direction you need to increase your pointer by 1, if you want to skip a row you need to advance to pointer with the size of one column.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Im sorry but can you please modify my code by what you mean  I don’t quite understand I’m very nooby sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do with pointers :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class matrix_t
{
public:
    
    // Dont focus too much on this constructor
    // it helps me making initialization of the content of
    // the matrix more easy
    template<std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t cols_v>
    explicit matrix_t(const int (&values)[rows_v][cols_v]) :
        m_columns{cols_v},
        m_rows{rows_v},
        m_data{new int[m_rows * m_columns]} // <== Allocate memory (normally use std::vector)
    {
        // point into data
        int* ptr = m_data;

        // copy the initialization data into contiguous memory
        for(std::size_t row = 0; row < m_rows; ++row)
        {
            for(std::size_t col = 0; col < m_columns; ++col)
            {
                *ptr = values[row][col];
                ++ptr;
            }
        }
    }

    ~matrix_t()
    {
        // always match new with a delete and a new[] with a delete[]
        delete[] m_data;
    }

    // function for calculating the right pointer
    // for row and column
    int* at(const std::size_t row, const std::size_t column)
    {
        int* ptr = m_data;
        ptr += 
        (
            (row * m_columns) +  // for each row you have to advance the pointer by m_columns (this is called stride)
            column // then add the column you need
       );

       return ptr;
    }

    bool is_symmetric()
    {
        // width and height match
        if (m_columns == m_rows)
        {
            // we only have to check values
            // - not on diagonal (they always match)
            // - in top-right of matrix (otherwise we will check values twice)
            for(std::size_t row = 0; row < m_rows; ++row)
            {
                for(std::size_t col = row + 1; col < m_columns; ++col)
                {
                    int* value1 = at(col,row);
                    int* value2 = at(row,col);
                    if ( *value1 != *value2  ) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    std::size_t m_columns;
    std::size_t m_rows;
    int* m_data;
};

int main()
{
    matrix_t m1
    {{
        {1,0},
        {0,1}
    }};
    assert(m1.is_symmetric());

    matrix_t m2
    {{
        {1,0,2},
        {0,1,0},
        {2,0,1}
    }};
    assert(m2.is_symmetric());

    matrix_t m3
    {{
        {1,2,3},
        {0,1,0},
        {2,0,1}
    }};
    assert(!m3.is_symmetric());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I even realized that in my Programm the incrementalism of ptr++; has to be undone after the for loop. I also thaught that I’m coding c++ because my compiler ( VSCode ) did not show any error.

Comment: VSCode is not a compiler it is an IDE (editor). And that often uses MinGW compiler (others can be used, but need to be installed). And so you use a C++ compiler, and the code is valid C++ (correct syntax). However, it is NOT the way you should write good C++.

Comment: How to write good C++ is described here : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines, though it might take a while for you to understand them. That's ok you need time to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect code like this using std::vectorstd::vector<int> as input.
`int array [c][r];` In your code isn't standard C++

```
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

class matrix_t
{
public:
    matrix_t(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>&& values) :
        m_values{values}
    {
        if ((m_values.size() == 0ul) || (m_values[0].size() == 0ul))
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument{"invalid matrix size"};
        }
    }

    bool is_symmetric()
    {
        auto size = m_values.size();
        // width and height match
        if ( size == m_values[0].size())
        {
            // we only have to check values
            // - not on diagonal (they always match)
            // - in top-right of matrix (otherwise we will check values twice)
            for(std::size_t row = 0; row < size; ++row)
            {
                for(std::size_t col = row + 1; col < size; ++col)
                {
                    auto& value1 = m_values[col][row];
                    auto& value2 = m_values[row][col];
                    if ( value1 != value2  ) 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_values;
};


int main()
{
    matrix_t m1{{{1,0},{0,1}}};
    assert(m1.is_symmetric());

    matrix_t m2{{{1,0,2},{0,1,0},{2,0,1}}};
    assert(m2.is_symmetric());

    matrix_t m3{{{1,2,3},{0,1,0},{2,0,1}}};
    assert(!m3.is_symmetric());
}
```